# Recursive function that determines if the first n characters in two different strings are the same

Tags: python, recursion

Here is the iterative solution:

```
def firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n):
    same = True
    for i in range(n):
        same &= string[i] == string2[i]
    return same

print(firstNCharsSame("apple", "appll", 5))# ->false
print(firstNCharsSame("aaaae", "appll", 5))# ->false
print(firstNCharsSame("apple", "apple", 5))# ->true
```

I am need to make a recursive function to do the same thing. I find recursion very confusing but here is my attempt.

```
def firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n):
    if n > 1:
        firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n-1)
    return string[n - 1] == string2[n - 1]
```

This effectively only checks if the last characters in the strings are the same. I need to `&` the all values returned by all the calls of this function like I have done in the iterative version but I am struggling to understand how I can access what the "inner(higher up the stack)" function returns from the "outer(lower down the stack)" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the recursive result with testing the current index.

```
def firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n):
    if n == 0: # base case
        return True
    if n > len(string) or n > len(string2):
        return False
    return string[n - 1] == string2[n - 1] and firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n-1)
```

Comment: It fails the test `print(firstNCharsSame("apple", "apple", 5))`. It should print true but it print false

Comment: Oh, nevermind. that was being being triggered due to `>=` in line `n >= len(string) or n >= len(string2)`. Very cool thank you.

Comment: Right, it should be `>`

Comment: I am struggling to understand this a little. Can you explain why base case always returns true please?

Comment: All zero-length strings are equal.

Comment: You'll only get to the zero case if you keep recursing through the first N characters and they're all equal.

Comment: And it returns `string[n - 1] == string2[n - 1] and firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n-1)` if some of them are different to each other right? But why?

Comment: Right. `X and Y` is only true if both `X` and `Y` are true. So if `string[n-1] == string2[n-1]` isn't true, that returns `False`.

Comment: So sholdn't it be that line that determines the final return value of the function? Why does it return `None` if I change the base case to `if n == 0: 
        return None`. This only happens if all the characters are the same

Comment: Because the last recursion returns `True and None`, which returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the base case as 0, and implement like so:

```
def firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n):
    if n == 0: 
        return True
    if n > min(len(string), len(string2)):
        return False
    return string[n - 1] == string2[n - 1] and firstNCharsSame(string, string2, n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
def firstNCharsSameRec(string, string2, current, n):
    if current >= n:
        return True

    if string[current] != string2[current]:
        return False

    return firstNCharsSameRec(string, string2, current + 1, n)
```

And calling it like this:

```
print(firstNCharsSameRec("apple", "appll", 0, 5))
print(firstNCharsSameRec("apple", "appll", 0, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the last parameter as a decreasing counter.  Just compare the first characters and recurse for the rest:

```
def firstNCharsSame(a, b, n):
    return not n or a and b and a[0]==b[0] and firstNCharsSame(a[1:],b[1:],n-1)
```